# Update already printed value to terminal and read it in java

Tags: java, terminal, console

I need to create some simple interface for an operator to validate some strings. I suppose that the simplest one is do it in the console.

There are next steps:

- The string is printed to the console
- Operator checks it. If the string is ok operator clicks `enter`, if there is a mistake he updates already printed string and clicks `enter`. It's important that operator doesn't type the string again because it can be long.
- Operator sees new string, etc.

Is it possible to implement this with a simple console in java? I try to use `PipedOutputStream` and `PipedInputStream` streams like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream pipeIn = new PipedInputStream(pipeOut);
    System.setIn(pipeIn);

    System.out.print("My string to verify");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pipeIn));
    String verified = br.readLine(); 
}
```

There are two problems:

- In terminal cursor cannot be moved to already printed string to edit it
- even if I press `enter` cursor is moved to the next line, it seems that `br.readLine();` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

From What I understand It just a game between String and user input this example use the input for a String of a User

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        String s = "My string to verify";
        System.out.println(s); 
        //Do what you need with s;
        //edit it
        String s2 = scanner.nextLine();

        bufferedWriter.write(s2);
        bufferedWriter.close();
        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I need to print some string to console, that be able to edit it manually in console, not in the code, and read edited string from console.